# Linq wildcard and NOT condition needed for LINQ statement

Tags: c#, .net, regex, linq

I was looking at some wildcard stuff for LINQ  - but not having much luck

Essentially there is a for loop in which these variables will change

```
varFirst = "ABC" 
varSecond = "DEF"
varThird = "GHI"
```

So for my wildcard search , I want to be sure  varFirst and varThird match , but varSecond is the wildcard and can be anything.

I was looking at regex, but I'm having trouble trying to understand how to do this.

```
var x = vidaBiliy.SponsorPackage.Where(s => s.Policy == varFirst + varSecond + varThird ).FirstOrDefault()
```

So in looping over the data I have a query above that is concatenating those 3 variables (they are changing prior to this based on values from a loop .    So in this case - I only want varFirst and varThird to be exact match ...  but varSecond can be anything.   I suppose the specs use  *** , but that just means anything is allowed

I was looking at  **regEx.IsMatch(item)** ,  but then I'm wondering how to achieve this.

Then I need another check for  " do search for the NOT condition"

Am I overthinking it or don't have enough information?

Comment: `Where(s => Regex.IsMatch(s.Policy, $"{varFirst}.*{varThird}") )`?

Comment: having fun with other options
`var arr = s.Policy.split(varSecond);
arr[0].constains(varFirst);
arr[2].constains(varThird);
`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew   so if s.Policy == varFirst + varSecond + varThird     ,  in your example - where is the varSecond ?

Comment: But you say `varSecond` should match anything, thus, I used `.*` - match any 0 or more chars other than a newline, as many as possible. Or do you mean you need to `Regex.Escape` the first and third arguments? `Where(s => Regex.IsMatch(s.Policy, $"{Regex.Escape(varFirst)}{varSecond}{Regex.Escape(varThird)}") )`

Comment: @Dalorzo   so in yours,  I would split the varSecond , but s.Policy doesn't exist outside the linq where clause ,   and constrains mean exact?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew   Oh - I see nice.    I like your answer,   Would the other answer even work in your opinion   ( technically its a comment )

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  i don't think an escape...    the first and last have to be exact match,  but second (middle) can be anything.

Comment: `.Where(s => Regex.IsMatch(s.Policy, $@"\b{varFirst}\b{varSecond}\b{varThird}\b")`? What do you mean by "exact match"?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  as it loops a query is looking for combined match in which wildcard suggesting the middle not matter  .   Thus  if in the loop  varFirst = ABC ,  varSecond = DEF  and varThird = GHI   then  if   s.Policy = ABC123GHI   ,  then it passes ok and the middle ( varSecond) can be anything.

Comment: Then why did you ask me "where is the varSecond"? :) You have just said it is irrelevant in the search. But now, I see that the regex must match the whole string, then just use `Where(s => Regex.IsMatch(s.Policy, $"^{varFirst}.*{varThird}$") )`

Comment: Well - because I didn't really understand the code.    so thus would your original comment work ?    Where(s => Regex.IsMatch(s.Policy, $"{varFirst}.*{varThird}") )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to only keep the items where the `Policy` property starts with `varFirst` and ends with `varThird`, you may use

```
.Where(s => Regex.IsMatch(s.Policy, $"^{Regex.Escape(varFirst)}.*{Regex.Escape(varThird)}$"))
```

This will create a regex like `^ABC.*DEF$` and will match any string starting with `ABC` and ending with `DEF`, having any 0 or more chars other than a newline in between.

If you need a partial match, remove the anchors, `^` and `$`.

The `Regex.Escape` method is required if the `varFirst` and `varThird` can contain special regex metacharacters like `(` or `[` that must be matched literally.

Comment: Alternatively `s.Policy.StartsWith(varFirst) && s.Policy.EndsWith(varThird)`, which probably reads a bit nicer for people not accustomed to regular expressions.

Comment: @Wiktor     I had 1 another  Not equal regex scenario .    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63800208/linq-condition-with-not-equal-to-condition-for-3-situations

Answer (score 1):

First, let's create a handy method to accept your mandatory parameters:

```cs
public static class StringUtils
{
    public static bool IsIn(this string source, params string[] values)
    {
        return values.Contains(source);
    }

    public static bool IsAny(this string source, params string[] values)
    {
        return values.Any(v => v.Contains(source)); 
    }

    public static bool WhenAll(this string source, params string[] values)
    {
        return values.All(source.Contains);
    }
}
```

In case if you want `varFirst` and `varThird` to exactly match with `Policy`:

```cs
var x = vidaBiliy.SponsorPackage.FirstOrDefault(s => 
            s.Policy.IsIn(varFirst, varThird) &&
                        Regex.IsMatch(s.Policy, varSecond));
```

In case if you want on of the `varFirst` and `varThird` to exactly match with `Policy`:

```cs
var x = vidaBiliy.SponsorPackage.FirstOrDefault(s => 
            s.Policy.IsAny(varFirst, varThird) &&
                        Regex.IsMatch(s.Policy, varSecond));
```

And the case when you want "ABC123GHI" (`Policy`) to contain "ABC" (`varFirst`) and "GHI" (`varThird`) and optionally match `Regex` (`varSecond`):

```cs
var x = vidaBiliy.SponsorPackage.FirstOrDefault(s => 
            s.Policy.WhenAll(varFirst, varThird) &&
                        Regex.IsMatch(s.Policy, varSecond));
```

---

Note: you don't need to apply `Where` and the `FirstOrDefault` but can combine them to one method.

Comment: as it loops a query is looking for combined match in which wildcard suggesting the middle not matter . Thus if in the loop varFirst = ABC , varSecond = DEF and varThird = GHI then if s.Policy = ABC123GHI , then it passes ok and the middle ( varSecond) can be anything.

Comment: I don't know the different between  IsIn and IsAny  ...

Comment: So varFirst and varThird  must be an exact match ,  but  varSecond can be anything - so I'm concerned which both last queries

Comment: @JeremyMiller, I think my last update `WhenAll` should match to your last comment output. Please check.

Comment: First and Third should have IsMatch ,     second is the wildcard

Comment: I gather the IsMatch is exact match so i'm lost on why  s.name ?  and only varThird. 
Also ,  WhenAll ?  Not sure what that means.  but  First is an exact, and Second is the wildcard - so I cannot imagine those being treated the same

Comment: Shouldn't this be reversed     s.Policy.WhenAll(varFirst, varThird) &&
                        Regex.IsMatch(s.name, varSecond));

Comment: @JeremyMiller, very sorry man, I was testing the above on my VS IDE and renamed variables incorrectly when putting the code to SO answer. Now it should be fine.

Comment: @TomStickel, to allow the user to pass any character instead of `varSecond`, including `.*` which will skip it or if there is a custom action then some other regex charset can be provided. There are of course two other options available: 1) remove `Regex.IsMatch(s.Policy, varSecond)` at all or use `|| Regex.IsMatch(s.Policy, varSecond)` instead of  `&&`.