# Linq condition with NOT equal for concatenation of 3 variables

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I do have a SO question that was very helpful, in which I needed a wildcard solution. However, I also need a "*NOT EQUAL TO*".

Example:

```
varFirst = "ABC"
varSecond = "DEF"
varThird = "GHI"
```

Normally, without an "*IS NOT EQUAL*":

```
var x = vidaBiliy.SponsorPackage.Where(s => s.Policy == varFirst + varSecond + varThird ).FirstOrDefault();
```

So, what someone helped me with was the wildcard in which say the `varSecond` could be *ANYTHING*.

```
.Where(s => Regex.IsMatch(s.Policy, $"^{Regex.Escape(varFirst)}.*{Regex.Escape(varThird)}$"))
```

That seems to be correct with exact matches on first and last variables and ANYTHING for the middle variable with `.*`.

However, with Regex, how do I do the same thing with that `varSecond` must NOT equal `DEF`.

Comment: Jeremy, I think you would have to just explain what you are trying to do.  It's unclear at the moment for me, sorry ...  what is your aim?

Comment: Take a look at the other question I listed.    var x = vidaBiliy.SponsorPackage.Where(s => s.Policy == varFirst + varSecond + varThird ).FirstOrDefault();    ,   so  say varSecond = "DEF"  , well , I want to make that a regex of it does NOT equal DEF  ,   thus  3 combinations I will end up having with first , second and third variables with 3 different queries.

Comment: Please don't write your question as a continuation of some other question! This makes it very very difficult to help you - please update your question to be a *standalone question*, with all relevant details. Thank you!

Comment: @Fattie  Updated.

Comment: @CoolBots   Ok, I understand.   I removed the other wildcard other question stuff and revised it.  have a look .  thx again

Comment: You could just add a negative look-ahead in there `$"^{Regex.Escape(varFirst)}(?!{Regex.Escape(varSecond)}).*{Regex.Escape(varThird)}$"`  Note in your example of ABC, DEF, GHI that it would match "ABCXDEFGHI" since "XDEF" is not "DEF".

Comment: By the way, this is very easy to check with tools like Regex101 - check out this saved example with your sample data and a negative lookahead: https://regex101.com/r/OE1KpJ/1

Comment: Have you looked at `string.StartsWith` and `string.EndsWith`?

Comment: @juharr   Thx.   If you want,  could you create a quick answer for the question ?   thx again

Comment: I have a solution with StartsWith and EndsWith which doesn't require a complex Regex.  Unfortunately, just as I was about to press "Post", the question closed.  Oh well.  It started with `int startMiddleEndLength = Starts.Length + NotMiddle.Length + Ends.Length;` and then `var results = Strings.Where(s => s.StartsWith(Starts) && s.EndsWith(Ends) && (s.Length != startMiddleEndLength || s.Substring(Starts.Length, NotMiddle.Length) != NotMiddle));` where the strings like `Starts` and `NotMiddle` are your three strings ("ABC", etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
$"^{Regex.Escape(varFirst)}(?!{Regex.Escape(varSecond)}{Regex.Escape(varThird)}$).*{Regex.Escape(varThird)}$"
```

This means, the match will fail in case between `varFirst` and `varThird`, there is only `varSecond` pattern. The expression looks like

```
^ABC(?!DEFGHI$).*GHI$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/D5PeIs/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `ABC` - `varFirst` pattern
- `(?!DEFGHI$)` - no `varSecond` + `varThird` patterns followed by the end of string
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than a newline
- `GHI` - `varThird` value
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Wait, so you wrote  varThird part twice?

Comment: @JeremyMiller Sure, you need to set the right-hand context for the second variable text in order to anchor it.

Comment: Seems like it is saying match first, second is not equal ,  match third and then wildcard the 3rd

Comment: The solution works [as expected](https://regex101.com/r/D5PeIs/1).

Answer (score 0):

How about something straight-forward and simple like this:

Setting up:

```
private const string Starts = "ABC";
private const string NotMiddle = "DEF";
private const string Ends = "GHI";

private const string StartMiddleEnd = "ABCDEFGHI";
private const string StartCloseEnd = "ABCXDEFGHI";
private const string StartAnyEnd = "ABCANYGHI";
private const string StartAnything = "ABCANYTHING";
private const string AnythingEnd = "ANYTHINGGHI";

private static readonly List<string> Strings = new List<string>
{
    StartMiddleEnd,
    StartCloseEnd,
    StartAnyEnd,
    StartAnything,
    AnythingEnd,
};
```

and then running:

```
public static void Test()
{
    int startMiddleEndLength = Starts.Length + NotMiddle.Length + Ends.Length;
    var results = Strings.Where(
        s => s.StartsWith(Starts)
             && s.EndsWith(Ends)
             && (s.Length != startMiddleEndLength ||
                 s.Substring(Starts.Length, NotMiddle.Length) != NotMiddle));
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

The output from this is:

```
ABCXDEFGHI
ABCANYGHI
```

Comment: How could I alter this so instead of middle is NOT,  instead the First and also the Last ?   I need to be able to check  for combinations of   each of the 3 scenarios in which  NotFirst , any second,  any third     and then one you have and finally     any first, any second   NOT third

Comment: The code for first and last is *very* simple. It would be easy to adapt to any rule set you want (including one you load at run time). The middle is more complicated, but rules could be establishedif thought through. It you want something like that, write up a very clear question, using some of the code here. But make it clear, include examples for each scenario. As if stands, I believe I've answered the question you asked

Comment: Yes, I need to answer a new question.   So I decided to use Linqpad and created all the other types of conditions for Not Start, Not Middle, Not End ... then  Wildcards of  Any Start ,  Any Middle,  Any End -   Then I go and try and plug it into my REAL SQL code and boom,  complains about not knowing what StartsWith and SubString is ...  I'm baffled as I spent a lot of time on it , but its like i'm not using Linq to SQL or something.    Thoughts before I write up a question ?  thx

Comment: You have no mention of your LINQ code talking to a database in your question.  When you use LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework, your LINQ code must be translatable to SQL code.  If you are talking to Entity Framework, you may want to look at something like `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbFunctions.Like`